# How can I stop ubuntu-mate-welcome appearing when I log in?

Tags: ubuntu-mate

How do I make `ubuntu-mate-welcome` stop appearing when I log in on Ubuntu MATE?

Comment: yes, I want to keep the welcome program from booting. help:)

Comment: @user830486 What is your Ubuntu MATE version?

Answer (score 2):

Found this via search.  For 18.04 Ubuntu Mate, you can turn this off from the Start menu:

System - Preferences - Personal - Startup Applications

At the very bottom is Welcome Ubuntu MATE Welcome autostart

Comment: This approach works, thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Googlers, in Ubuntu-MATE 20.x it has become a snap plugin:

```
snap remove ubuntu-mate-welcome
```

(removal has to happen for each existing user)

Answer (score 0):

There should be a checkbox called "Open Welcome when I log in" on the main screen which you can uncheck to hide the welcome.

Or if you really want you can uninstall and purge the package ubuntu-mate-welcome

Comment: OP might need to know: `sudo apt purge ubuntu-mate-welcome` command should be used to accomplish second method.

Comment: Where can I see the checkbox on the main screen?...

Comment: @user830486 probably into the welcome window, you got this checkbox (or if there is a parameter button, it must be inside it)